# Fantasy book secondary character teaches the hero shape shifting magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a fantasy book with an unusual secondary character. She teaches  the hero shape-shifting magic and walks with crutches. She is involved romantically with him, but dies, which leads to him trying to avenge her. The story takes place in a tower. I don't remember how that hero got into magic or that particular tower nor why the evil protagonist is, well, evil... the only striking character was that woman.
thanks

Yes, the secondary character used crutches. Additional details I remember: She was described as striking, they could both become eagles ( not a werewolf story) the tower was both an academy and kinda military since they guarded something.

yeah! you nailed it! thank you!!! it's indeed E. Cooper's Wild Hunt.

Comment: You've got some good details, but take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help you add in some more.

Comment: I'm assuming that she walks on crutches, rather than teaching the hero how to?

Comment: "She is involved romantically with him, but dies, which leads to him trying to avenge her. " - how is that unusual?

Comment: not the romance thing of course... a disabled woman in a powerful position and romanticaly involved with anyone... im not talking about the usual blind woman that "sees"

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark, but is it [Songs of the Earth by Elspeth Cooper](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9419570-songs-of-the-earth). It has been a long time since I read it, but I'm fairly sure the main character went to a tower to learn magic, learned shape-shifting and got into a relationship with a teacher.